# cocos2d alternative in UiKit?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uikit

new in ios application development with uikit,can any one tell me what is alternative code of cocos2d replacScene In UiKit.used segue model but problem is i want use it programmatically like cocos2d.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can call the segue programatically by giving it an identifier and then using the following function

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"<segue identifier>" sender:<the sending view controller>];
```